# Error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

I am trying to use @angular/materials in my app and it is compiling successfully, however I am getting the following error:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(136,20): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(154,104): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts(53,15): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts(55,18): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
```

This does not seem to be a common problem, does anyone have any idea how to resolve?

Using:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 6.0.0-rc.14-29bf024
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 6.0.0-rc.14-29bf024
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: Update your angular version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` 6RC versions (`6.0.0-rc.14-29bf024)`, which probably depend on Angular version 6.

Either downgrade the `@angular/material` package to latest stable version (if you're building directly for production) or try upgrading angular to the `6.0.0-rc.6` version (if you're aiming your release after the angular 6 stable comes out).

Comment: The default versions of _material_ and _cdk_ are for Angular 6 and don't work with Angular 5. If upgrading Angular is not an option, downgrading the packages should work. I did: `npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.4` and `npm install --save @angular/cdk@5.2.4`. (I think it's just a coincidence that the latest version 5's of material and cdk are both 5.2.4).

Comment: I don't think it is a coincidence since they're developed together.

Answer (score 13):

```
npm uninstall @angular/material  --save
npm install @angular/material@5.2.4 --save
```

It worked for me.

Angular version is `5.2.1`.

Comment: if anyone using sdk and animations with that then install both their version as 5.2.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **dependencies issue**, need to re-install dependencies.

In package.json **match your angular version with "@angular/material"**, it should be similar. 
Then run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue. Upgrading Angular to 6 is not yet an option for us, as we have a dependency that does not support anything over Angular 5 (currently rethinking that dependency). Taking Material down to version 5 was an option, but not ideal, because the reason we went to 6 was it fixed a pretty nasty bug on material tabs.

What worked for us was to upgrade Node to 8.10. I'm not sure why that resolved it, but it did.

Hope it helps.